# Reading ARFF from ZIP with zipfile and scipy.io.arff

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy, arff, python-zipfile

I want to process quite big ARFF files in scikit-learn. The files are in a zip archive and I do not want to unpack the archive to a folder before processing. Hence, I use the zipfile module of Python 3.6:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
from scipy.io.arff import loadarff

archive = ZipFile( 'archive.zip', 'r' )
datafile = archive.open( 'datafile.arff' )
data = loadarff( datafile )
# …
datafile.close()
archive.close()
```

However, this yields the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./m.py", line 6, in <module>
    data = loadarff( datafile )
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/io/arff/arffread.py", line 541, in loadarff
    return _loadarff(ofile)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/io/arff/arffread.py", line 550, in _loadarff
    rel, attr = read_header(ofile)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/io/arff/arffread.py", line 323, in read_header
    while r_comment.match(i):
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

According to [loadarff documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.arff.loadarff.html), `loadarff` requires a file-like object.
According to [zipfile documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html), `open` returns a file-like `ZipExtFile`.

Hence, my question is how to use what `ZipFile.open` returns as the ARFF input to `loadarff`.

Note: If I unzip manually and load the ARFF directly with `data = loadarff( 'datafile.arff' )`, all is fine.

Comment: loadarff requires a file-like object. So you should read into a in-memory file like object. Can you try this ? `in_mem_fo  = StringIO(archive.read('datafile.arff'))`

Comment: This yields the Error: File "m.py", line 7, in <module>
    in_mem_fo = StringIO(archive.read('datafile.arff'))
TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes

Comment: But your idea let me find a solution: `in_mem_fo = StringIO(archive.read('datafile.arff').decode("utf-8"))` or `in_mem_fo = StringIO(archive.read('datafile.arff').decode("ascii"))`

Comment: Great. I have added an answer which might be a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from io import BytesIO, TextIOWrapper
from zipfile import ZipFile
from scipy.io.arff import loadarff

zfile = ZipFile('archive.zip', 'r')
in_mem_fo = TextIOWrapper(BytesIO(zfile.read('datafile.arff')), encoding='utf-8')
data = loadarff(in_mem_fo)
```

Read `zfile` into a in-memory `BytesIO` object. Use `TextIOWrapper` with `encoding='utf-8'`. Use this in-memory buffered text object in `loadarff`.

Edit: Turnsout `zfile.open()` returns a file-like object so the above can be accomplished by :

```
zfile = ZipFile('archive.zip', 'r')
in_mem_fo = TextIOWrapper(zfile.open('datafile.arff'), encoding='ascii')
data = loadarff(in_mem_fo)
```

Thanks @Bernhard

Comment: Thanks, once again, your answer has inspired me to another solution which I find even more elegant, because it avoids putting all in memory first: `textfile = TextIOWrapper(datafile, encoding='ascii')` and then
`data = loadarff( textfile )`. I suggest you put something like this into your solution as an edit and I accept so others can use it.